# box2d - calculate same time for every FPS amount

Tags: c++, box2d

i created a simple game with SFML and Box2d. 
But i got a problem. The time of the physics are depending on the framerate of the player.

I already got the FPS of the player, but i´m not really sure how to get the same time. I also found no formula... Can someone help me?

```
while (window.isOpen()) {

    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();


    window.display();

    sf::Time time = clock.getElapsedTime();
    float fps = 1.0f / time.asSeconds();
    std::cout << 1.0f / time.asSeconds() << std::endl;
    world.getBWorld()->Step(60/1, 8, 3);
    clock.restart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a delta time.

> In graphics programming, the term **delta time** is usually used for variably updating scenery based on the elapsed time since the game last updated. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing)

```
sf::Clock deltaClock;
while (window.isOpen()) {
{
    // ...
    sf::Time dt = deltaClock.Restart(); // Restart returns the elapsed time
}
```

Then you can move your player with:

```
mySprite.Move(velocity * dt.AsSeconds());
```